# context - WithDeadline() vs WithTimeout()

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Below code:

```
// Sample program to show how to use the WithDeadline function
// of the Context package.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type data struct {
    UserID string
}

func main() {

    // Set a duration.
    // duration := 150 * time.Millisecond
    duration := time.Now().Add(3 * time.Second)

    // Create a context that is both manually cancellable and will signal
    // a cancel at the specified duration.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), duration)
    defer cancel()

    // Create a channel to received a signal that work is done.
    ch := make(chan data, 1)
    // Ask the goroutine to do some work for us.
    go func() {

        // Simulate work.
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)

        // Report the work is done.
        ch <- data{"123"}
    }()

    // Wait for the work to finish. If it takes too long move on.
    select {
    case d := <-ch:
        fmt.Println("work complete", d)
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("work cancelled")
    }
}
```

---

is using `WithDeadline` for sending timer'd `cancel()`. This can be done using:

```
duration := 150 * time.Millisecond

// Create a context that is both manually cancellable and will signal
// a cancel at the specified duration.
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), duration)
```

---

Internally, `context.WithTimeout` calls the `context.WithDeadline` function and generates the deadline by adding timeout to the current time.

How `context.WithTimeout()` different from `context.WithDeadline()`

Comment: "How context.WithTimeout() different from context.WithDeadline()?" -- You answered your own question in the paragraph before: "Internally, context.WithTimeout calls the context.WithDeadline function and generates the deadline by adding timeout to the current time." If you read the code, what else do you want to know?

Comment: No! Everyone in this post answers/comments incorrectly. Timeout and Deadline has their own definition in the computing. Timeout specifies a duration/interval to complete a task while the deadline specifies an absolute point in time to complete the task. So, use whichever you need :)

Answer (score 17):

`WithTimeout` is a convenience function for executing `WithDeadline(parent, time.Now().Add(timeout))`.

The functions differ in how the application specifies the deadline.  Otherwise they are the same.

Call the function appropriate for the value you have on hand.

Answer (score 9):

> How context.WithTimeout() different from context.WithDeadline()

The first takes a duration after which to cancel from now, the second an absolute time to call cancel as explained in the documentation which is worth reading as usual.